# Enable checks on question titles for weak word selection

Tags: feature-request, question-titles, quality-filter

Today I was editing a migrated question in SO, which contained the word "Help" just to be greeted with a message:

[image]

I was all O_O when saw this. When I wrote http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8720/lets-try-and-write-useful-titles I didn't know about this *feature*. I know there are corner case scenarios where the word "help" may be useful in the title, but in practice, most titles that contain these words are weak and not descriptive about the problem at hand. Can this check be activated in Ask Ubuntu, but instead of saying "not allowed" maybe "not recommended" and only in case they contain a weak word choice (ie. "please help me solve my problem") gets rejected.

Some data might be useful: of the 193 290 questions on the site, +60k has the word help (+30%), +82k has the word problem (+50%). I think that is a indicative that something very bad is going on with the titles.

Comment: Do you think people will bother about it? at least those who don't bother reading the about or taking a tour?

Comment: @AdityaPatil we can hope... if this doesn't work, then harsher actions ensued.

Comment: oooh, maybe we can put "crash" and "freeze" in there!